# php/mysql I have a simple form, how do i get the info submitted into datavase and displayed on main page?

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms, wamp

I am still practicing with wamp, phpmyadmin, and mysql so i am a bit unsure on how to do this.

Right now i have the html file with a simple form code, what do I do next as far as getting the information into the database.

where does this code go? in the html file or a new php file:

```
<?php
$database = "hit";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$conn = mysql_pconnect($localhost, $root, $password) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);
mysql_select_db('hit');
?>
```

and then the code to getting whatever is submitted displayed on the main page... can someone help me out with this code? Also, would it go in this same php file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should not use `mysql` extension to php because it is already deprecated and is soon to be removed. [This article](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) pretty much covers the subject.

Now, you have basically two options:

1) Create one html file with form which points to you second (php) file with it's `action` attribute. Then you can access user input with $_REQUEST array, e.g. if you have `<input type=text name=id>`, you will be able to access user value through $_REQUEST["id"].

2) Create only one file of .php extension, which contains both html code (outside any `<?php ?>` tags), and php code in these tags. In this case, you can skip `action` attribute of form (or set it to this very php file), but in you php code you will have first to check weather form submit button have already been clicked or not. This can be done with simple `is(isset($_REQUEST["doit"]))` check, where `doit` should be replaced with you submit button name.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write a php code in a .html extension file. You have to write this in .php extension file.

Also make you use correct syntax to connect, this is wrong

```
$conn = mysql_pconnect($localhost, $root)
```

Try something like this

```
$conn = mysql_pconnect($hostname, $username, $password);
```

Comment: ahh im dumb. i removed $password because i figured it didnt need it since i didnt have one. thank you!

Comment: You CAN write php in a html file. Simply amend the .htaccess file, add "AddType application/x-httpd-php .html"